# Can I compute per-row aggregations over rows that satisfy a condition using PySpark?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Consider the following toy PySpark data frame:

```py
+----+-----+
|name|value|
+----+-----+
|   A|    1|
|   A|    3|
|   A|    4|
|   A|    5|
|   A|    9|
|   B|    1|
|   B|    3|
|   B|    6|
|   B|    7|
|   B|    8|
+----+-----+
```

For each row `X`, I would like to determine how many rows `Y` with `Y.name == X.name` have `Y.value` in range `[X.value - 3, X.value + 3]`. For rows `Y` that satisfy those conditions, I would also like to compute the average `value`:

```py
+----+-----+-------------+--------------+
|name|value|n_vals_in_rng|avg_val_in_rng|
+----+-----+-------------+--------------+
|   A|    1|            3|     2.6666667| # (1 + 3 + 4) / 3 = 2.6666667
|   A|    3|            4|          3.25| # (1 + 3 + 4 + 5) / 4 = 3.25
|   A|    4|            4|          3.25| # ...
|   A|    5|            3|           4.0|
|   A|    9|            1|           9.0|
|   B|    1|            2|           2.0|
|   B|    3|            3|     3.3333333|
|   B|    6|            4|           6.0|
|   B|    7|            3|           7.0|
|   B|    8|            3|           7.0|
+----+-----+-------------+--------------+
```

Can I do this efficiently in PySpark? If so, how? Is it better to use Pandas to solve this problem? Note that my real dataset has ~400k rows and ~8k distinct names in the `name` column.

---

Below is my solution so far. It gives the correct result, but takes forever on a large dataset (several hours for a data frame with ~400k rows).

First, I group the data frame by `name` and I collect all `values` into a list stored as a new column.

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import pyspark.sql.types as T
import numpy as np

# df is the data frame defined above

# define a df to be nested
df_to_nest = df.groupBy("name").agg(F.collect_list("value").alias("values"))

# df_to_nest.show():
#   +----+---------------+
#   |name|         values|
#   +----+---------------+
#   |   A|[1, 3, 4, 5, 9]|
#   |   B|[1, 3, 6, 7, 8]|
#   +----+---------------+
```

I then join this aggregated data frame (`df_to_nest`) with the original `df`:

```py
# join with the original data frame
df = df.join(df_to_nest, "name", "left")

# df.show()
#   +----+-----+---------------+
#   |name|value|         values|
#   +----+-----+---------------+
#   |   A|    1|[1, 3, 4, 5, 9]|
#   |   A|    3|[1, 3, 4, 5, 9]|
#   |   A|    4|[1, 3, 4, 5, 9]|
#   |   A|    5|[1, 3, 4, 5, 9]|
#   |   A|    9|[1, 3, 4, 5, 9]|
#   |   B|    1|[1, 3, 6, 7, 8]|
#   |   B|    3|[1, 3, 6, 7, 8]|
#   |   B|    6|[1, 3, 6, 7, 8]|
#   |   B|    7|[1, 3, 6, 7, 8]|
#   |   B|    8|[1, 3, 6, 7, 8]|
#   +----+-----+---------------+
```

Last, I create a [user-defined function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.2/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.udf) (UDF) to process each row.

```py
# define a UDF to process each row
def process_row(row):
    vals_in_range = [x for x in row.values if abs(x-row.value) <= 3]    
    return (len(vals_in_range),
            float(np.mean(vals_in_range)))

input_schema = F.struct([df[x] for x in df.columns])

output_schema = T.StructType([
    T.StructField("n_vals_in_rng", T.IntegerType(), nullable=True),
    T.StructField("avg_val_in_rng", T.FloatType(), nullable=True),
])

udf = F.udf(process_row, output_schema)

# apply the UDF
df= df.select("name", "value", "values", udf(input_schema).alias("new_cols"))

# unroll the new columns
df= df.select("name", "value", "new_cols.*", "values")
```

Result:

```py
# df.show():
#   +----+-----+-------------+--------------+---------------+
#   |name|value|n_vals_in_rng|avg_val_in_rng|         values|
#   +----+-----+-------------+--------------+---------------+
#   |   A|    1|            3|     2.6666667|[1, 3, 4, 5, 9]|
#   |   A|    3|            4|          3.25|[1, 3, 4, 5, 9]|
#   |   A|    4|            4|          3.25|[1, 3, 4, 5, 9]|
#   |   A|    5|            3|           4.0|[1, 3, 4, 5, 9]|
#   |   A|    9|            1|           9.0|[1, 3, 4, 5, 9]|
#   |   B|    1|            2|           2.0|[1, 3, 6, 7, 8]|
#   |   B|    3|            3|     3.3333333|[1, 3, 6, 7, 8]|
#   |   B|    6|            4|           6.0|[1, 3, 6, 7, 8]|
#   |   B|    7|            3|           7.0|[1, 3, 6, 7, 8]|
#   |   B|    8|            3|           7.0|[1, 3, 6, 7, 8]|
#   +----+-----+-------------+--------------+---------------+
```

Comment: Have you looked into window functions in spark? I believe this could be achieved better through windowing functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done with window functions and higher order functions. It should be more efficient than UDF.

```py
df.withColumn("value", col("value").cast("int")) \
    .withColumn("values", collect_list("value").over(Window.partitionBy("name"))) \
    .withColumn("in_range", expr("filter(values, v -> abs(v - value) <= 3)")) \
    .withColumn("n_vals_in_rng", size(col("in_range"))) \
    .withColumn("avg_val_in_rng",
                expr("aggregate(in_range, 0, (acc, value) -> value + acc, acc -> acc / n_vals_in_rng)")) \
    .select("name", "value", "n_vals_in_rng", "avg_val_in_rng") \
    .show()
```

You can read more about `filter` and `aggregate` functions here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/

Comment: This is a neat solution! Just note that it requires Spark 2.4+

Answer (score 0):

While I liked the [solution proposed by barteksch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64599474/1606707), I have found another solution that works with Spark 2.3 (and lower), and is better-suited for my particular case.

Instead of collecting values in range in a column, the idea is to create a row for each pair of values with the same `name` and with difference of at most 3. This can be done by exploding the data frame via a self-join, and filtering.

Before using this approach, be aware that **it can potentially create a huge intermediate dataset**, so make sure it makes sense in your case. For my dataset with ~400k rows, the exploded dataset had almost 400 million rows, but only about 9 million were kept after filtering. The whole script took around 10 minutes to run.

```py
# assign an index per row unique over a window defined by `name`
df = df.withColumn("id", F.row_number().over(Window.partitionBy("name").orderBy("value")))

# join the dataset with itself
df_exploded = df.select("name", "id", "value").join(
    df.select("name", F.col("value").alias("other_value")), "name")

# only keep rows where (value, other_value) are within 3 of each other
df_exploded = df_exploded.filter(F.abs(F.col("value") - F.col("other_value")) <= 3)

# aggregate over groups defined by (name, id)
df = df_exploded.groupBy(["name", "id"]).agg(
        # since `value` is constant per group, just take the max to retrieve it
        F.max("value").alias("value"), 
        # compute the actual aggregations: count, mean
        F.count("other_value").alias("n_vals_in_rng"),
        F.mean("other_value").alias("avg_val_in_rng")
    )
```

Result:

```py
# df.show():
#   +----+---+-----+---------------+------------------+
#   |name| id|value|n_vals_in_range|  avg_val_in_range|
#   +----+---+-----+---------------+------------------+
#   |   A|  1|    1|              3|2.6666666666666665|
#   |   A|  2|    3|              4|              3.25|
#   |   A|  3|    4|              4|              3.25|
#   |   A|  4|    5|              3|               4.0|
#   |   A|  5|    9|              1|               9.0|
#   |   B|  1|    1|              2|               2.0|
#   |   B|  2|    3|              3|3.3333333333333335|
#   |   B|  3|    6|              4|               6.0|
#   |   B|  4|    7|              3|               7.0|
#   |   B|  5|    8|              3|               7.0|
#   +----+---+-----+---------------+------------------+
```